# How to change the first letter of xml element to lower case using XSLT?

Tags: xml, xslt

I can easily use this sample in my xslt to lowercase all the letters in the element names.

```
<xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:element name="{
        translate(name(.),
        'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ',
        'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz')}">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

However, my requirement is to change only the first letter to lower case in a case where the element name is something like "MasterAccountNumber".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
<xsl:element name="{
        translate(substring(name(), 1, 1),
        'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ',
        'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz')}{substring(name(), 2)}">
```